# Custom UIButton to drill up from table view?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem

Ive put in a custom "Back" UIBarButtonItem, which is from an Image i made in photoshop. Ive managed to make it appear just fine, my problem is making it work.

My button does nothing, im assuming because i havent assigned any actions to it. I just dont know the correct syntax to do so?

Heres my code

```
    UIImage *buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"BackButton.png"];
        UIButton *backButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        [backButton setBackgroundImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        backButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, buttonImage.size.width, buttonImage.size.height);

// Im assuming this is where i need to put the action...
        //[backButton addTarget:self action:@selector(.......) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 
                                                 initWithCustomView:backButton];
```

Basically, i want my new custom backbutton to function just like the default one in a regular UITableView

regards, 
Andyy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in IB or you can do it in code with a call to `addTarget:action:forControlEvents:` for `UIControlEventTouchUpInside` to invoke a method (action) when the button is tapped.  For example:

```
[backButton addTarget:self action:@selector(backButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

This is documented in [UIControl class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html), UIButton is a subclass of UIControl.

You'll need a method which will be called when the event occurs, which I called `backButtonPressed:` in my code above.  This method takes one parameter, the object sending the event, something like this:

```
-(void)backButtonPressed:(id)sender
{
    // NOTE: assumes self is your UIViewController
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```